# Python: ValueError message for CausalImpact library Summary() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, time-series

I am getting a value error when I try to get the summary report using the Causal Impact library on Python. Strangely, everything else runs fine such as:

1. Model diagnostics plot
2. The fit and .plot() functions
3. post_period_response.mean() is not NaN

I have checked the data and the .inferences table for NAs but I cannot see any. This really seems like a strange error to me and I cannot work this out.

See traceback below and my code further below.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/z2/cr7wgffj7jv1yf4jb205tbwm0000gn/T/ipykernel_42059/102416755.py in <module>
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('xmode', '')
----> 2 print(custom_impact.summary())
        global print = undefined
        global custom_impact.summary = <bound method CausalImpact.summary of <causalimpact.analysis.CausalImpact object at 0x7fe90a6147f0>>

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/causalimpact/analysis.py in summary(self=<causalimpact.analysis.CausalImpact object>, output='summary', width=120, path=None)
    734 
    735         mean_resp = post_point_resp.mean()
--> 736         mean_resp_fmt = int(mean_resp)
        mean_resp_fmt = undefined
        global int = undefined
        mean_resp = nan
    737         cum_resp = post_point_resp.sum()
    738         cum_resp_fmt = int(cum_resp)

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

```
treat = 633
end = 120

y = df_ts['logged'].reset_index(drop = True)[:treat + end].replace(np.nan, 0) 
X = df_ts[['precip', 'windspeed', 'uvindex']].reset_index(drop = True)[:treat + end]
X = np.log(X + 1).replace(np.nan, 0)

post_period_response = y[treat:].copy().reset_index(drop = True)
y[treat: ] = np.nan

ucm_model = UnobservedComponents(endog=y, 
                                 level="llevel",
                                 exog= X, 
                                 autoregressive = 2,                       
                                 freq_seasonal=[{'period': 6*30,
                                                'harmonics': 1}]
                                )
res_tf = ucm_model.fit(disp=False)
print(res_tf.summary())

res_tf.plot_components(figsize = (25,15), alpha = .1)
plt.show()


custom_impact = ci.CausalImpact(ucm_model=ucm_model,                           
                                post_period_response=post_period_response,
                                alpha  = .1                                            
                                )
custom_impact.run()
custom_impact.plot(["original", "pointwise"])
print(custom_impact.summary())
```